# Multiple select queries execution one after other

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having six select queries with different where conditions if first select query returns null it should check the next select query and follows. what is the best approach to follow for writing it as stored procedure in SQL server.

Comment: Different where conditions against the same table? What is the point of this flow, to not execute the second and later queries if the first one gave results? At the cost of potentially hitting the table six different times? Are the queries at least ranked by most likely to return results first?

Comment: Yeah, against the same table. The point here is like Priority check if first one gives result no need to check second and follows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @@rowcount

```
DECLARE @OperatorID INT = 4, @CurrentCalendarView VARCHAR(50) = 'month';
declare @t table (operatorID int, CurrentCalendarView varchar(50));
insert into @t values (2, 'year');

    select operatorID - 1, CurrentCalendarView from @t where 1 = 2
if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) 
begin
    select operatorID + 1, CurrentCalendarView from @t where 1 = 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you can achieve this like below sample. You can go in this way.

```
if NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) 'x' FROM table WHERE id =@myId) 
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT  TOP(1) 'x' FROM table2 WHERE id = @myId2) 
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) 'x' FROM table 3 WHERE id = @myID3)
    BEGIN
    END 
  END 

END
```

Comment: Except this doesn't return any results

Comment: Yes, @AaronBertrand I think conditionally he can go with this what your thought?

Comment: @RajatJaiswal here your select query selecting single row but my select query has more than 10 rows writing select query 6 times looks weird can we use only where condition in IF NOT EXISTS block??

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share your existing query and data to understand your question in a more better way.